# How to join a series into a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

So I counted the frequency of a column 'address' from the dataframe 'df_two' and saved the data as dict. used that dict to create a series 'new_series'. so now I want to join this series into a dataframe making 'df_three' so that I can do some maths with the column 'new_count' and the column 'number' from 'new_series' and 'df_two' respectively.

I have tried to use merge / concat the items of 'new_count' were changed to NaN

**Image for what i got(NaN)**

[image: Screen Shot]

df_three

number  address name  new_Count
14  12 ab   pra   NaN
49  03 cd   ken   NaN
97      07 ef   dhi   NaN
91  10 fg   rav   NaN

**Image for input**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Input**

new_series
        new_count
12 ab   8778
03 cd   6499
07 ef   5923
10 fg   5631

df_two
number  address name
14  12 ab   pra
49  03 cd   ken
97      07 ef   dhi
91  10 fg   rav

[image: Screen Shot]

**output**

df_three
number  address name  new_Count
14  12 ab   pra   8778
49  03 cd   ken   6499
97      07 ef   dhi   5923
91  10 fg   rav   5631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you forget parameter `on`:

```
df = df_two.join(new_series, on='address')
print (df)
   number address name  new_count
0      14   12 ab  pra       8778
1      49   03 cd  ken       6499
2      97   07 ef  dhi       5923
3      91   10 fg  rav       5631
```

Comment: there is an error . and to fix it I had to convert the series into a dataframe. even after that the values were converted into NaN

Comment: it seems like my notebook was messed up due to repeated try. I just restarted it and ran the code again it worked. thanks